# Validate dynamic field jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Good afternoon, I came across the following question.

I'm using the jQuery Validation plugin to validate my form v1.13.0 client side.

Is working just fine.

But the problem I can not solve it is:

I have a field name "product []", which is an array.
I may have one or I may have 20 products in this array.

Here is my Code:

```
data_emissao:   {required: true},
forma_pagamento:    {required: true},
produto[]:  {required: true}, // tried this with no sucess
```

Anyone ever run into this problem?

Comment: You probably wanna use `produto` w/o the `[]`

Comment: not intendi! as would

Answer (score 2):

Two issues...

1)  If your field name contains brackets, dots or other special characters, then you must enclose the name in quotes.

```
"produto[]":  {
    required: true
}
```

2)  However, unless the `input` contains this exact name, `name="produto[]"`, then it will not work as you cannot declare an array within the `rules` option of `.validate()`.  The `rules` option only accepts a list of individual field names.

---

Two possible solutions...

1) You could use the `.rules()` method as follows.  Using a jQuery "starts with" selector to select the entire array and a jQuery `.each()` to apply the `.rules('add')` method to every field in this group.

```
$('[name^="produto"]').each(function() {  // select elements using "starts with" selector
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        // other rules
    });
});
```

2) However, if the only rule is `required`, then you would not need to declare it using any JavaScript at all.  You could just use the `required` HTML5 attribute instead, and the jQuery Validate plugin will still pick it up.

```
<input type="text" name="produto[0]" required="required" />
<input type="text" name="produto[1]" required="required" />
<input type="text" name="produto[2]" required="required" />
<input type="text" name="produto[3]" required="required" />
<input type="text" name="produto[4]" required="required" />
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `produto` as an array, you must specify its index or it wouldn't work as expected. Try using `produto[0]` to indicated that you require at least one value on your array.