# How to validate using jQuery Validate plugin, array input name

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

if I give index in input array then only required working other validation not working

```
<input type="text" name="batch_no[0]"> 
<input type="text" name="batch_no[0]">
```

---

```js
   $( "#batch-form" ).each( function() {                
        $(this).validate({
            rules: {
                "batch_no[]": {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5,
                    maxlength: 20,
                    alphanumeric: true
                }
               },
            });
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This issue is mentioned in the documentation as well as many question posted here.  Please use the search function.

Comment: Also, using the Code Snippet feature is pointless when you don't include enough code to run anything.

Comment: The answer give in the above links not working , As I mentioned that in the input array I used index but still it is not working .

Comment: There were four answers linked above and the code works when properly implemented.  Read all four, now five.  Also, like I said in first comment, you could use the search function as well.  1)  You must have a unique `name` attribute on every `text` input and 2) use an index in the array to ensure the name is unique.  And this:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/26022085/594235